# HaProxy Configurations Error while setting up multi proc environment

Tags: configuration, load-balancing, haproxy

I want to achieve 6000/sec requests and trying to setup HaProxy with multi proc settings but getting this error:

> cpu-map expects a process number including 'all', 'odd', 'even', or a
>   number from 1 to 64, followed by a list of CPU ranges with numbers
>   from 0 to 63

Following are the configurations I'm using.

```
global

daemon
maxconn 200000
maxsslconn 200000    

#stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
stats socket 127.0.0.1:14567
nbproc  6
    cpu-map auto:1/all 0
    cpu-map auto:2/all 1
    cpu-map auto:3/all 2
    cpu-map auto:4/all 3
    cpu-map auto:5/all 4
    cpu-map auto:6/all 5

stats bind-process 6

# Default SSL material locations
ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
crt-base /etc/ssl/private

# Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
# For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
#  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/

ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
```

and

```
global

daemon
maxconn 200000
maxsslconn 200000    

#stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
stats socket 127.0.0.1:14567
nbproc  6
    cpu-map 1 0
    cpu-map 2 1
    cpu-map 3 2
    cpu-map 4 3
    cpu-map 5 4
    cpu-map 6 5

stats bind-process 6

# Default SSL material locations
ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
crt-base /etc/ssl/private

# Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
# For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
#  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/

ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
```

Nothing is working as expected.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to map each process to a thread. Have you tried `cpu-map auto:1-6 0-5`? I don't believe you can have multiple cpu-map options.

Comment: I have Tried using `cpu-map 1 0` mean process ID 1 & cpu 0.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested? `cpu-map auto:1-6 0-5`

Comment: I'm testing with that today,